# XSL - move promote child node to parent node and distinct-value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have an xml file that contains elements that are parents instead of child, where a child element should be the parent. here is an example:

```
<root>
 <sub-area number="1">
  <name>West Viking</name>
  <condition>good</condition>
  <area>
   <name>Viking</name>
   <condition>average</condition>
  <area>
 </sub-area>
 <sub-area number="2">
  <name>East Viking</name>
  <condition>good</condition>
  <area>
   <name>Viking</name>
   <condition>average</condition>
  <area>
 </sub-area>
 <sub-area number="3">
  <name>North Viking, South Viking</name>
  <condition>good</condition>
  <area>
   <name>Viking</name>
   <condition>average</condition>
  <area>
 </sub-area>
 <sub-area number="4">
  <name>West Utshire</name>
  <condition>good</condition>
  <area>
   <name>Utshire</name>
   <condition>good</condition>
  <area>
 </sub-area>
 <sub-area number="5">
  <name>East Utshire</name>
  <condition>good</condition>
  <area>
   <name>Utshire</name>
   <condition>good</condition>
  <area>
 </sub-area>
 <sub-area number="6">
  <name>North Utshire, South Utshire</name>
  <condition>average/condition>
  <area>
   <name>Utshire</name>
   <condition>good</condition>
  <area>
 </sub-area>
</root>
```

What I would like to do in simplify this document by sub-areas being child nodes of the area. For example:

```
<root>
 <area name="Viking">
  <condition>average</condition>
  <sub-area name="West Viking">
   <condition>good</condition>
  </sub-area>
  <condition>average</condition>
  <sub-area name="East Viking">
   <condition>bad</condition>
  </sub-area>
  <condition>average</condition>
  <sub-area name="North Viking">
   <condition>average</condition>
  </sub-area>
  <sub-area name="South Viking">
   <condition>good</condition>
  </sub-area>
 </area>
 <area name="Utshire">
  <condition>good</condition>
  <sub-area name="West Utshire">
   <condition>good</condition>
  </sub-area>
  <condition>average</condition>
  <sub-area name="East Utshire">
   <condition>bad</condition>
  </sub-area>
  <condition>average</condition>
  <sub-area name="North Utshire">
   <condition>good</condition>
  </sub-area>
  <sub-area name="South Utshire">
   <condition>good</condition>
 </area>
</root>
```

Everything I tried failed so far. Looked at doc and forums, I couldn't find anything. I don't know how to approach this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is a simple grouping `<xsl:for-each-group select="sub-area" group-by="area/name"><area name="{current-grouping-key()}">...</area></xsl:for-each-group>`.

Comment: As Martin says, it's a grouping problem. When you come at it from this angle, it's sometimes called "hierarchy inversion", but it's exactly the same problem as grouping, and there is a vast literature on how to tackle grouping problems both in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to bring your source XML to a proper shape:

- add "/" to closing `area` tags,
- change `/condition>` to `</condition>` (in 1 place).

And now back to the main business:

- Start from groupping `sub-area` tags on `area/name`.
- Then for each area name create parent (`area`) tag.
- Within this area put `sub-area` tags - the content of the current group.

And here is a complete solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="sub-area" group-by="area/name">
        <xsl:element name="area">
          <xsl:attribute name="name" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
          <xsl:sequence select="area/condition"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:element name="sub-area">
              <xsl:attribute name="name" select="name"/>
              <xsl:sequence select="condition"/>
            </xsl:element>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's exactly what I was looking for.